# how to make popout section scroll smoothly using html, css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a site where i have to make a functionality of scrolling a section from left to right and vice versa. Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Now what i have to do is if i click on the plus icon showing in blue section then it's section should slightly scroll and extend smoothly from left to right as you can see in next image.

[image]

and if i click on the plus icon in pink colored section then it should moves from right to left means the functionality should work vice versa.
as it is showing in next image.

[image]

I want to know what is the best way to design this functionality using html, css and jQuery

Comment: use css and transform and addClass and removeClass

Comment: I have used transform and add remove class but the process is not working smoothly

Comment: set transform to all

Comment: Is there any demo available for such sort of feature ?

Comment: wait i'm providing an example

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, but if you check first image in my question than you will find that at start both are square divs it changes its structure when we click on plus icon and slightly extends that div with some degree at least 20 degrees, now after this if i click on second div than it should be changed it structure like mirror image of first div.

Comment: please have a look on all three images

Answer (score 1):

There is an other example using jquery animate I hope it helps:
[image]

```js
width=$('#ppp').width();
$('.sec button').click(function(){
$(this)
.parents('.sec').animate({width:width*0.15-20})
.siblings('.sec').animate({width:width*0.85-20});

$('.sp').toggleClass('flip');
});
```

```css
.sec{
  width:calc(50% - 20px);
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:90px;
}

.sec button{
margin-top:30px;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.sp{
transition:0.5s all;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
margin:0;
width:0px;
}

.sp-r{
border-top: 90px solid red;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;
margin-right:-10px;
}

.sp-r.flip{
border-top:0 transparent;
border-bottom: 90px solid red;
}

.sp-l{
border-bottom: 90px solid green;
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
margin-left:-10px;
}

.sp-l.flip{
border-bottom:0 transparent;
border-top: 90px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ppp">
<div class="sec" style="background:red;">

<button>+</button>
</div><!--
--><DIV CLASS="sp sp-r"></DIV><!--
--><DIV CLASS="sp sp-l"></DIV><!--
--><div class="sec" style="background:green;">
  <button>X</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this you have increased the width of div this same i need but the extended section should be in triangle form as it is showing in images in my question.

Comment: check the answer now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 $(this).parent().css({'width':'60%'});
 $(this).parent().siblings().css({'width':'40%'});
})
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
}
.container div{
  transition:0.5s;
}
.container .div1{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background:blue;
}
.container .div2{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">
<button>Click</button>
</div>
<div class="div2">
<button>Click</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This can be done but the thing is that i have to extend it in atleast 25 degree